# on fabric.js how to get the item(count) on active object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fabricjs

How can I get the canvas.item(#) or src of active object in fabric.js.
I have the following. but get_id() function returns "Layer_1" every time for any object

```
 function load() {
        fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
        fabric.loadSVGFromURL('images/test.svg', function (objects, options) {
            var shape = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
            canvas.add(shape.scale(1));
            shape.set({ left: 200, top: 100, ZIndex: 10 }).setCoords();
            canvas.renderAll();
        }) ; }


  function get_id() {
        var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
        var newCanvasId = obj.id;
        alert(newCanvasId)
}
```

I would like to get unique id or item(#) image name or src or .... to identify this active object.  any help please?

Comment: How are your SVGs being generated? Do you know the unique ID you want each image to have when you are loading them? If so can you just add the ID under shape.set when you load the image.

Comment: Hi Amanda,  You were right. after adding id under set for each object I could get individual items now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks after adding id to the object under set, I can get each object by thier id.

Thanks